# Problema con animación en LazyColumn de Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, kotlin, jetpack-compose

Quiero añadir una animación a una LazyColumn para que cuando aparezca un elemento por debajo, se haga una animación en la que el elemento haga un efecto de fadeIn y scale.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun AnimatedLazyColumn() {

    val items = remember { ('A'..'Z').map { it.toString() } }
    val listState = rememberLazyListState()

    Column(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {

        val lastVisibleItemIndex = listState.layoutInfo
            .visibleItemsInfo
            .lastOrNull()?.index ?: 1f

        LazyColumn(
            state = listState,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(16.dp),
            contentPadding = PaddingValues(
                horizontal = 16.dp,
                vertical = 30.dp
            ),
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {

            itemsIndexed(items) { index, item ->

                val animateAlpha by animateFloatAsState(
                    targetValue =
                    if (lastVisibleItemIndex == index) {
                        0f
                    } else {
                        1f
                    },
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 300,
                        easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                    ),
                    label = ""
                )

                val animateScale by animateFloatAsState(
                    targetValue =
                    if (lastVisibleItemIndex == index) {
                        0.6f
                    } else {
                        1f
                    },
                    animationSpec = tween(
                        durationMillis = 300,
                        easing = LinearOutSlowInEasing
                    ),
                    label = ""
                )

                Box(
                    contentAlignment = Alignment.Center,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .scale(animateScale)
                        .alpha(animateAlpha)
                        .height(80.dp)
                        .fillMaxWidth()
                        .background(Color.Blue)
                ) {
                    Text(item, color = Color.White)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Funciona como quiero, pero debido a la condición que he establecido, todos los elementos de la lista se animan excepto el último, que permanece invisible

[image]

Me gustaría que la animación llegara hasta el último elemento y no se quedara oculta, ¿qué puedo hacer? No sé si es la mejor manera de hacerlo, así que también acepto consejos.

Comment: No sé usar animaciones todavía, pero creo que tu tampoco las estás entendiendo. Estás estableciendo siempre el valor final (`targetValue`) a 0 cuando debería ser 1 ya que quieres que el elemento sea visible. Además, como el último elemento siempre será el último elemento visible, la opacidad queda siempre en 0. Podrías probar haciendo que todos los elementos sean invisibles y con la animación volverlos visibles. `targetValue = 1` para todos.

Comment: @Mateo el problema es que hasta donde se, para que haga el efecto de animación, debe pasar de un target a otro, sino lo que haré será que los objetos siempre tendrán targetValue a 1f por lo que no se animará

Comment: ¿Qué tal si cambias la condición por `if (index in firstVisibleItemIndex..lastVisibleItemIndex) 1 else 0`? Así los ítems serían transparentes cuando no se muestran en la pantalla. Para la escala también deberías probar algo similar.

Comment: tratas de obtener el índice del último elemento a partir del último elemento que es visible, esto no es correcto.